# Am I in the wrong place? (where are the organization/org-chart and staffing tags?)

Tags: discussion, tags

I asked a question about organizational structure, but when doing so noticed that there are no tags starting with `org` or `staff`.  Are there other tags that are appropriate? Should I be asking these on another site?  Should these be added? (I don't have nearly enough rep here)

Comment: What is the question you are wanting to ask that you think is missing a tag?

Comment: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/110555/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-management-layer-between-upper-leadership-and-staff

Comment: I Think if you asked about how to create a business case for this projected position the question would be acceptable.  (possibly even good)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for bringing your question to meta.  Our tag set is not in the greatest shape.  I just created [org-structure](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/org-structure) and gave it a one-line wiki.  If people think there's a better name, let us know and we can rename.  Please feel free to propose edits to the tag wiki.

Answer (score 4):

Monica did a good job answering the question you asked about tags, but I also wanted to address why your original question wasn't being well received. You were primarily asking for the pros and cons of having managers. That is a *very* broad topic and isn't something we can really answer here. We are looking for specific questions with specific goals that can result in specific answers. I encourage you to take a look at our Help Center pages on what makes a question off-topic here [[1]](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) [[2]](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Looking at your situation, there certainly are some questions you could ask that would be a good fit here. Some examples that come to mind:

> - I am seeing XYZ problems. How can I address these problems?
> - I am seeing XYZ problems which I believe are because all of the staff report directly to the owners. Would adding another management layer help?
> - How do I approach my boss about adding another management layer in the company?

No matter what you ask, I think you would need to (concisely) explain what problems you are seeing that you think would be solved by adding management. If you skip straight to requesting more managers without telling us *why*, you run the risk of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's always good to have outside opinions to confirm that your proposed solution will work.